# Changing screen on android without using button

Tags: android

I want to change the screen in android using an intent, but without using using button, wanted to use it with any method I use within an IF ELSE, how can I do?

Comment: Try to improve your question. Use more than 1 sentence. Tell us what have you done to do what you try to accomplish. What have happened? Any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to implement a method that implements your Intent. Then you can use any of this to call it:

- Timer
- Sensor
- Service
- Another Intent
- External devices
- Another View like a TextView, ImageView, etc. Whatever you want as long as it is not a Button.
- Magic?

Comment: You do not show me one exemplode code for me to study changing the screen without button?

Comment: @Pixelayer you do not give one example of why you might need to do this. If you want to do it then you must have a reason. Please explain in more detail what/why you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I am creating a IF ELSE.

example:

if (return == 1)
{
   Changing Screen
}
else
{
   Does nothing
}

only this

Comment: @Pixelayer then where is the problem? In your `if` put the `Intent` to launch the new `Activity`. Personally, I would use a Magic object...I hadn't thought about that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous but in general an activity can be launched using a listener for any widget (e.g. OnSeekBarChangeListeners for seekbars, OnCheckedChangeListeners for radio groups, etc.). This would be implemented the same way as if you were launching an activity from an onClickListener for a button.

An activity can also be launched from another activity after a certain period of time in the onCreate method for the initial activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_file);

    //More code

    thread.sleep(long time); //The time to wait in milliseconds

    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: I am creating a IF ELSE. example: if (return == 1) { Changing Screen } else { Does nothing } only this

Comment: To launch an activity with an if-else statement simply use: if(condition){ startActivity(intent) }, no need for an else clause to do nothing.